# Promise через callback

Tags: javascript, promise

Написал небольшой пример, никак не могу додуматься, как заставить это работать и правильно ловить ошибки. Функцию `helper3(next)` нельзя менять. Подскажите как исправить.

```js
function helper(error, results) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (error) reject(error);
    if (results) resolve(results);
  });
}

function helper3(next) {
  next('err', 'eee');
}

function helper2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(helper3(helper));
  });
}

helper2().then(res => console.log('1', res)).catch(err => console.log('2', err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как внутри `helper2` Promise всегда успешно завершен, нет возможности попасть в catch.

Для исправления нужно, чтобы вызывались и `resolve` и `reject` параметры.

Так как они должны вызываться в соответствии с результатами `helper`, то и передавать их надо в продолжение `helper`. Для передачи, нужно вызвать [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), но чтобы вызвать `then`, нужно вызвать саму функцию `helper`.

Для решение, нужно обернуть вызов в функцию:

```
helper3((err, succ) => helper(err, succ).then(resolve, reject))
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
function helper(error, results) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (error) reject(error);
    if (results) resolve(results);
  });
}

function helper3(next) {
  next('error', 'eee');
}

function helper2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    helper3((err, succ) => helper(err, succ).then(resolve, reject));
  });
}

helper2().then(res => console.log('1', res)).catch(err => console.log('2', err));
```